# Use a wordpress action in an external script

Tags: php, wordpress

i need to use an ACTION of a WordPress plugin in an external script.

At the beginning of the script I entered:

```
require_once ("../wp/ wp-blog-header.php ');
```

and I would like to use:

```
add_action ('render_view', array ($this, 'name_view'));
```

located in the constructor of my plugin.

The attempts I have made are:

```
do_action ('render_view', $view);
```

with result:

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined function render_view ()
```

Has anyone already met this fact?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can include the WordPress in the external script via below statement:

```
$wordpress_dir = "Write here wordpress directory path";
define('WP_USE_THEMES', false); 
require_once $wordpress_dir."/wp-load.php";
```